# Formatting date/time value for date picker control

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using the following code to get a `DateTime` value from the server in my ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application and set an `<input />` element to that value.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '?handler=InitProductTransfer',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'sourceId': sourceId, 'sourceType': sourceType },
})
.done(function (response) {
    // Set timestamp
    var $timeStamp = $modal.find('#TimeStamp');
    $timeStamp.val(response.timeStamp);   // <====== ERROR HERE!
}
.fail(function (response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
});
```

The problem is that the date/time is not in the correct format.

The format of `response.timeStamp` is `2023-10-31T15:23:55.0038809`.

Does JavaScript have a function to format the date for a date/time `<input />` element? Or is it necessary to manually format the date to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vanilla JavaScript you can create a `Date` object and pass it to the input using the `valueAsDate` property:

```js
let timeStamp = "2023-10-31T15:23:55.0038809";

document.getElementById("dateInput").valueAsDate = new Date(timeStamp);
```

```html
<input id="dateInput" type="date" />
```

If your element has `type="datetime-local`, you can use the following:

```
document.getElementById("dateInput").value = new Date(timeStamp).toISOString().slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: This does work. Thanks. But unfortunately, my input element is generated by ASP.NET and the type is set to `datetime-local`, which doesn't work.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("dateInput").value = new Date(timeStamp).toISOString().slice(0, -1);` for `datetime-local`.